# Как прижать footer к низу

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="news"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать заменить absolute на fixed

и добавить body margin 0

```
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
```

Comment: fixed это только поможет там где мало контента

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, наша страница на уровне футера делится на 3 блока:

```html
<header>шапка</header>
<main>основное содержание</main>
<footer>футер</footer>
```

Тогда родительскому контейнеру, пусть это будет див с классов .wrapper, мы задаём:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

например так:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: ну это получаеться а на странице где много контента всякого то там он просто зависает на середине экрана

Comment: тогда `min-height: 100vh;`